# How to get the value from a control in a headertemplate in a gridview?

Tags: gridview, drop-down-menu, controltemplate, radgrid

I have a RadGrid (Telerik)[almost the same as a gridview] with a headertemplate and a itemtemplate:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="field" SortExpression="field">
     <HeaderTemplate>
          <asp:Label Width="100%" Text="<center>Field</center>" runat="server" />
          <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlField" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlField_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%" />
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblField" runat="server" Text="testert" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

That same radgrid has also 2 other colums with the same templates and 1 column with a button. Now when the user chooses a value in the above shown dropdownlist, new items load in the other 2 itemtemplates. But when the user has choosen the values he wants, the user can press the button. When the user presses the button, the system should add a row with the values as labels. But i can't find a way to get the values from the dropdownlists in the headertemplates when the onClick event of the button occurs. Can anyone tell me how I can access the selected values of the dropdownlists in the headertemplate from a OnClick event of a button?

P.S. I develop ASP.NET/C#!

Thanks in advance!!

Kind regards,
Wesley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you store the selected values from each dropdown into hidden form field and on button OnClick, access those hidden form fields? Form Viewstate should be enabled.

Comment: It's only posible when I put an event on the SelectedIndexChanged event of the 3 dropdownlists, and I try to prevent that because it slows everything down. Is there no other way?